# PHP Undefined index in XAMPP?

Tags: php, html, xampp, echo

My code is extremely simple, but I have no idea what I've done to cause this error.

Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8

```
<form name="shuffle" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit" value="Shuffle">
</form>
```

PHP code: `echo str_shuffle($_POST['value']);`

Comment: If the form is not submitted then you should get this error. Try `if(isset($_POST)){ echo str_shuffle($_POST['value']); }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: the value will be posted only if the form is submitted.so untill it is submitted there is noting called 'value' and the error will be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have posted form in same file. so you need to check if form is submitted or not.

Try like this:

```
 if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    echo str_shuffle($_POST['value']);
    }
```

Comment: @Alanay : did you get the point? why it was happen? let me know if you need more explanation and do not forgot to mark it as accepted if it works :)

Comment: Yes I think I do, I'm just gonna have to try remembering the syntax for next time. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you call $_POST['value'] when form has not been previously submitted you get a warning that the key of $_POST is not defined.

Try to define the variable anyway. So that if you have sent the form, take the value of the field, otherwise the value is FALSE

```
$value = isset($_POST['value']) ? $_POST['value'] : FALSE; //$value is always defined
if($value !== FALSE){
//something like
echo str_shuffle($value);
}
```

[PHP isset function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)